# How to get current month and Last month in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am wondering if I can get last month and current month in Redshift? I looked at functions at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_DATE_TIME_functions.html

For current month, I guess I can do the following:

```
LEFT(CURRENT_DATE, 7)
```

For previous month, I came up with the following:

```
LEFT(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1), 7)
```

But I am wondering if there is a simpler way of doing these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE);

SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE - '1 month'::interval);
```

Comment: --Can we use this solution, but somehow get it back into a timestamp? Like I am looking for the calendar month beginning and end which contains the current date.-- Nm, found date_trunc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html